# ESP8266 Wemos D1 min pro - how to change TCP_SND_BUF?

Tags: esp8266, c, tcpip

Is there any way to change the TCP send buffer size (TCP_SND_BUF) on this module ?

Now it is equal to `TCP_SND_BUF = 2 * TCP_MSS = 2 * 1460 = 2920`.

Editing `lwipopts.h` doesn't make any difference.

The same question applies to `ΤCP_MSS`, `TCP_WND` etc.

I am using v2 Higher Bandwidth variant. Platform is Microchip Studio with vMicro Arduino addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out the hard way :

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/discussions/8616

---

Install **Git** for windows (https://git-scm.com/download/win)

Install **MinGW** for windows (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw)

In **MinGW** installation manager, enable:

- mingw-developer-toolkit
- mingw32-base
- mingw32-gcc-g++
- msys-base

*(not sure if all are necessary but just in case)*

put *C:\MinGW\bin* in Windows PATH (check this https://www.rapidee.com)

### **reboot PC**

rename **C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe** to **C:\MinGW\bin\make.exe**

open **bash** terminal (just type bash in run)

*(from now on assume that hardware files are in \Documents\Arduino\hardware\esp8266com\esp8266)*

go to *\tools\sdk\lwip2*

optional: change **lwip options** in *\tools\sdk\lwip2\builder\glue-lwip\arduino\lwipopts.h*

(caution : **NOT** *\tools\sdk\lwip2\include\lwipopts.h*, this will be overwritten !)

type in bash: **make install** to build libraries in *\esp8266com\esp8266\tools\sdk\lwip2\builder*

type in bash: **make clean** to clean *\esp8266com\esp8266\tools\sdk\lwip2\builder*

finally copy new libraries to *\esp8266com\esp8266\tools\sdk\lib*

Comment: May all richnesses of the world reach you, my friend, for I have been going crazy the entire day yesterday trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The macro you are trying to tweak is for reference only and does not control the size of the buffer.

On the ESP8266 the IP stack (and much of the rest of the system) is precompiled as `.a` libraries. Changing things like the `TCP_SND_BUF` macro will never change what has been compiled into those libraries. Instead all it will do is cause problems of buffer overruns and corrupted data as other code is then given incorrect information about the size of the buffer.